# Control flow guard C#

Tags: c#, .net-security

I've read an article about Control Flow Guard (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secbp/control-flow-guard). I'm tried to enable it in my C# application, but the way how it was done in article not working in my Visual Studio 2017. Can somebody tell me how to enable it?

Comment: You don't. CFG is a feature that applies only to unmanaged code. C# is not C++. Just like DEP and ASLR, whether to use this feature (and how) is up to the runtime, not you.

Comment: If you are native compiling .net, this does apply.